# Why is C++ getting wrong parameter values from C# for a function returning a custom struct

Tags: c#, c++, interop, immutability

Suppose I have the following C# Console application calling a C++ library.

```
internal static class Program
{
    private struct NumberContainer
    {
        internal int Number1 { get; }
        internal uint Number2 { get; }

        internal NumberContainer(int number1, uint number2)
        {
            Number1 = number1;
            Number2 = number2;
        }

        public override string ToString()
            => $"{Number1}, {Number2}";
    }

    [DllImport("CPlusPlusTargetLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern int Add(int number1, uint number2);

    [DllImport("CPlusPlusTargetLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    private static extern NumberContainer Compose(int signedInput, uint unsignedInput);

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var unsignedInput = args.Any() && uint.TryParse(args.First(), out uint unsignedValue) ? unsignedValue : 0;
        var signedInput = args.Count() > 1 && int.TryParse(args.ElementAt(1), out int signedValue) ? signedValue : 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Adding {0} and {1}...", signedInput, unsignedInput);
        Console.WriteLine("Result = {0}", Add(signedInput, unsignedInput));

        Console.WriteLine("Composing {0} and {1}...", signedInput, unsignedInput);
        Console.WriteLine("Composed {0}", Compose(signedInput, unsignedInput));
    }
}
```

And the following header file in `CPlusPlusTargetLibrary.dll`:

```
#pragma once

struct NumberContainer
{
    const signed long Number1;
    const unsigned long Number2;

    NumberContainer(const signed long number1, const unsigned long number2)
        : Number1(number1),
        Number2(number2)
    {
    }
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) signed long __cdecl Add
(
    signed long number1,
    unsigned long number2
);

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) NumberContainer __cdecl Compose
(
    signed long signedInput,
    unsigned long unsignedInput
);
```

And the following corresponding CPP file for that header:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "TargetFunctions.h"

extern "C"
{    
    __declspec(dllexport) signed long __cdecl Add(signed long number1, unsigned long number2)
    {
        return number1 + number2;
    }

    __declspec(dllexport) NumberContainer __cdecl Compose(signed long number1, unsigned long number2)
    {
        return NumberContainer
        (
            number1,
            number2
        );
    }
}
```

Given `5` as the `unsignedInput` in C# and `-8` as the `signedInput`, why is it that `Add` correctly receives `-8` and `5` when the breakpoint on the `return` statement in its C++ implementation is hit, but `Compose` receives `5` and `710724189`?

Also, as a side, the immutable struct `NumberContainer` fails to initialize throwing a `write access violation.` exception once `Number1(number1)` is hit - albeit this is after the faulty values have been received so this probably isn't relevant to the 1st problem I'm trying to resolve.

If I flip the call order, `Compose` then receives `5` and `1817521252` but I cannot proceed any further to see what `Add` receives due to the aforementioned exception.

From debugging, I have found that placing a breakpoint on the opening curly brace of either implementation shows incorrect parameter values; after this line, the parameter values are both correct for `Add` but for `Compose` the 1st parameter is consistently correct if it were the 2nd parameter whilst the 2nd parameter appears to be some random value in memory.  I'm thinking something's offset the arguments so that the first one is being discarded somewhere between the C# and C++ but what is doing that, I am not sure (I've also tried using `__stdcall` with `CallingConvention.StdCall` and `CallingConvention.Winapi` both to the same end result).

Comment: Does anything change if you remove `NumberContainer`'s constructor, and make the members non-const?

Comment: Have you considered using a cli/c++ wrapper? While it requires an extra project it should avoid some of the complexity in the marshalling since you can do the type conversions yourself.

Comment: @canton7 Yes, with `Compose` first `number1` now comes in as `5` and `number2` as `3146159005`; flipped back `Add` still comes in correctly but `Compose` comes in as `4` and `10415680` - so the immutability of the struct doesn't appear to be the cause of the problem.

Comment: @JonasH I hadn't but it sounds like it could be an answer ;-)

Comment: If you own the c/c++ code you should turn it into a c++/CLI project.  This makes talking to native code trivial and does way with troublesome p-invoke

Comment: @MickyD The real code luckily is code I have the source for (although it calls other 3rd party code).  Do you know what the template is called for the CLI project or how to convert an existing project into a CLI project?

Comment: Are you compiling as 32-bit or 64-bit? When your C# program is running, what's the value of IntPtr.Size?

Comment: `IntPtr.Size` is `8` - I'm compiling both the C# and C++ projects as 64-bit.

Comment: Try compiling as 32-bit.Or if compiling as 64-bit, use `Int64` for C# and `long long` for C++.

Comment: Well, that now gives me a `System.EntryPointNotFoundException: 'Unable to find an entry point named 'Compose' in DLL 'CPlusPlusTargetLibrary.dll'.'` - interestingly though it was able to call `Add` before that happened.

Comment: Clean the project before recompiling.

Comment: I did find the output directory for the C++ project was wrong (it was building to the Solution Directory instead of the Project Directory) but even manually deleting the C# project's target directory didn't resolve that error.  I've confirmed that new DLLs get written to the target directory upon a clean build in 32-bit.

Comment: Just to confirm too, `IntPtr.Size` is `4` when running in 32-bit in C# and `Add` is still successfully called - it's just `Compose` that fails.

Comment: Does anyone know how to create a CLI project?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this article I found the answer: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66243/Marshaling-with-C-Chapter-3-Marshaling-Compound-Ty

All I had to do was mark my C# `NumberContainer` struct with the `StructLayoutAttribute` like this, and the parameter values started coming in correctly!

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 64)]
private struct NumberContainer
{
    internal int Number1 { get; }
    internal uint Number2 { get; }

    internal NumberContainer(int number1, uint number2)
    {
        Number1 = number1;
        Number2 = number2;
    }

    public override string ToString()
        => $"{Number1}, {Number2}";
}
```

I believe what was happening before was the struct was being assumed to be 32-bit by C++ and thus the first parameter of `-8` (a 32-bit signed integer) was making up the 2nd half of the default 64-bit `NumberContainer` struct on the C++ side.  However, having said this: if I change `Size` to `32` or `128` and do a rebuild, it weirdly continues to pass the correct parameter values in!  If `Size` is omitted from the attribute though, then the parameter values come in incorrectly as before.

I seem to have resolved the original problem and the immutable struct successfully instantiates and returns from the C++ code, but the aforementioned mystery about the `Size` parameter is still unsolved.  If someone has an answer to this then I'll happily accept it over my own.

Comment: The following posts may be helpful: Common Visual C++ 64-bit Migration Issues: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/common-visual-cpp-64-bit-migration-issues?view=msvc-160,  Default Marshaling Behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/default-marshaling-behavior, and Built-in types: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/built-in-types .